# expect regular expression matches everything or nothing

Tags: regex, bash, expect

From the following output

```
user@machine ~]$ myScript
Warning: Permanently added '2.2.2.2' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
Cookie: 65251-403              EventID: 8900000000

Answer:
```

How may I capture only the line "Cookie: 65251-403              EventID: 8900000000" into a variable?

The following code currently captures everything from "Warning" up to "Answer:"

```
set [lindex $argv 0]
set [lindex $argv 0]
set timeout 20

spawn -noecho ssh -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no -oUserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -l $user $ip

set chalStr "(Cookie)"
expect  {
    $chalStr {
         set challengeString $expect_out(buffer)
         puts "RegEx matched:  $challengeString"
    }
}

interact {
        "ver" { send "sversion|more" }
}
```

If I enclose the expression as ^Cookie$ then nothing is matched.

Comment: $ means end-of-line.  Try just ^Cookie, or ^Cookie.*$

Answer (score 0):

Capture this `Cookie: 65251-403 EventID: 8900000000` with `^Cookie.*?$`

**[EDIT] after your comment**

You need to add the multiline flag - see it working here: https://regex101.com/r/7XBeOF/1

If you want to match same thing without the `m` flag you can also do so: `Cookie.*?\n`.

See it working here:
https://regex101.com/r/7XBeOF/2

Comment: As soon as I add a ^ or a$ the expression stops matching, or at least I get nothing printed out from the puts line of the script

Comment: How do I add the  m flag? Using the Cookie.*?\n option shortens the captured expression leaving out the Response part but still a couple of new lines mix in

Comment: I am not sure of your current text being multiple lines or not did you see the regex101 links? give a try to sth more complex: `Cookie.*\n?(.(?=Answer:))` (if you are on single line mode)

Comment: I don't know the "expect" language. What do u get with `Cookie.*`?

Comment: I did see your examples and they make all the sense in the world but inside the expect block they dont work. The last alternative yields similar results. Ultimately what I am trying to achieve is to take the cookie and the event id values to build a new string and put it back on the screen. So we know the variable is capturing more than needed, I guess the next question is how to manipulate that string to extract those values, preferrably into separate variables

Comment: With Cookie.* the program captures the entire output from beginning to end

Answer (score 0):

The way I managed to accomplish what I needed was using the expect command regexp:
http://wiki.tcl.tk/989

By doing this I was able to split the pieces I needed. For example:

```
regexp {\d{5}-\d{3}}  $expect_out(buffer) part2
```

`\d{5}-\d{3}` matches 5 digits a dash and 3 more digits

`$expect_out(buffer)` takes the output text from the buffer, this is the part that gets compared against the previous regexp

`part2` tells the system to assign the matched text into variable called part2

Antoni suggestions are correct, however within expect the $expect_out(buffer) may be the reason why it behaves differently